# Download Records in to csv file

Tags: lightning-web-components, csv

I have created a to Download contacts in to csv filw.

retrieved the data needed. There is a problem in converting to csv.
I have tried everything. Below is my code.

ERROR is:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach');

```js
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import retrieveContacts from '@salesforce/apex/downloadContcatApexClass.retrieveContactMethod';
export default class DownloadContacts extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    @track contacts;
    @track error;

    @api invoke(){
        retrieveContacts({ recordIdAccount: this.recordId })
            .then((result) => {
                console.log('line 12:' + result);
                this.contacts = result;
                this.error = undefined;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.error = error;
                this.contacts = undefined;
            });

        var columnEnd = ',';
        var lineEnd = '\n';

        // Get the CSV header from the list.
        var keys = new Set();
        this.contacts.forEach(function (record) {
            Object.keys(record).forEach(function (key) {
                keys.add(key);
            });
        });

        keys = Array.from(keys);
        var csvString = '';
        csvString += keys.join(columnEnd);
        csvString += lineEnd;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.contacts.length; i++) {
            var counter = 0;
            for (var sTempkey in keys) {
                var skey = keys[sTempkey];
                // add , after every value except the first.
                if (counter > 0) {
                    csvString += columnEnd;
                }
                // If the column is undefined, leave it as blank in the CSV file.
                var value = this.contacts[i][skey] === undefined ? '' : this.contacts[i][skey];
                csvString += '"' + value + '"';
                counter++;
            }
            csvString += lineEnd;
            var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
            hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv);
            hiddenElement.target = '_self';
            //hiddenElement.download = component.get("v.fileName");
            document.body.appendChild(hiddenElement); //Required for FireFox browser
            hiddenElement.click(); // using click() js function to download csv file
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're running asynchronous code in your JavaScript. The [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for `retrieveContacts` is likely resolving *after* you attempt to parse the contacts into a CSV. So `this.contacts` is *null* when `forEach()` is run on it (likewise it will have no records, so no keys to iterate over).

```js
   @api invoke(){
        retrieveContacts({ recordIdAccount: this.recordId }) // #1
            .then((result) => { // #3 runs once a response is received
                console.log('line 12:' + result); 
                this.contacts = result;
                this.error = undefined;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.error = error;
                this.contacts = undefined;
            });

        // ...code removed for brevity

        this.contacts.forEach(function (record) { // #2 runs immediately after retrieveContacts
            //...
        });
```

If this is your first time working with asynchronous JavaScript I'd encourage you to read some tutorials on promises and how they work ([Salesforce's Promise doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_promises.htm)). But in general, what you want to do is something more like this:

```js
retrieveContacts({ recordIdAccount: this.recordId }) // #1
            .then((result) => {
                this.contacts = result;
                this.parseCsv(this.contacts); // <-- parse your content once you have it
                this.error = undefined;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.error = error;
                this.contacts = undefined;
            });

parseCsv(contacts) {
    // parse into CSV
}
```